# How to change selected item position to top in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `recyclerview` in that I want to change item's position dynamically to top after selecting the item of `recyclerview`.

Please suggest best way to achieve the above problem?

Comment: on clicking of item ,remove the item at that postion from array list and add it at 0 position

Comment: Yes!! It worked!!Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to swap selected item with top item in list, then notify your adapter about position change.
A sample code would look like:

```
Collections.swap(orderItems.getItems(), position, 0);
                notifyItemMoved(position, 0);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: any suggestion on how to combine this awesome algorithm with layout items changed? every item on the zero / first position? @amit-srivastava

the zero items: with an icon.
the rest item: without an icon.

when swap takes, place. the current item doesn't change the layout.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
String Item = List.get(position); 
List.remove(position);  // remove item from the list
List.add(0,removedItem); // add at 0 index of your list
notifyDataSetChanged();
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 20); // scroll recyclerview to top
```

**OR**

```
recyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0)  // scroll recyclerview to top
```

**OR**

```
recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);  // scroll recyclerview to top
```

Comment: i try your code but but it's not Scrolling Top Position.

Answer (score 2):

add below code in onclick of item,

```
String removedItem = actualList.remove(position); 
//actualList is list used to populate recylerview and position is selected 
//item position
actualList.add(0,removedItem);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have different [cases like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921796/how-to-change-selected-item-position-to-top-in-recyclerview?rq=1#comment96625240_48922313), we can achieve this approach from [@manohar-reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921796/how-to-change-selected-item-position-to-top-in-recyclerview?rq=1#comment84850039_48921796) and call `notifyItemChanged(position)` it will also call the `onBindViewHolder`, then update your layout accordingly.

*In this case, if the 0 item has a different layout from the other items

You might wanna read [this reference](https://medium.com/@noureldeen.abouelkassem/difference-between-position-getadapterposition-and-getlayoutposition-in-recyclerview-80279a2711d1) for getting the item position correctly

thanks to @amit-srivastava answer and @manohar-reddy