# Select only one image in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` which has some Arrays there.

ArrayList with Strings and ArrayList with Integer. Strings are like url and Integer is the photo.

When the app is open for first time the first item is selected.
I have another method for click which makes another item as selected and this works, but the problem is that the first item stays as selected and so for every image click makes as selected, I want only one item to be selected and take a color.

This is my code.

Adapter of RecyclerView

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private int selectedItem;

    private ArrayList<Integer> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mSearchUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> images, ArrayList<String> SearchUrl, Context context) {
        mImages = images;
        mContext = context;
        mSearchUrl = SearchUrl;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.s_engine_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        selectedItem = 0;
        if (selectedItem == i) {
            viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
        }
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mImages.get(i))
                .into(viewHolder.image);
        viewHolder.searchUrl.setText(mSearchUrl.get(i));

        viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
                selectedItem = i;

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImages.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView searchUrl;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngine);
            searchUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngineText);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the MainActivity.class

```
public void intSearch() {
    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_bing);
    mSearchUrl.add("https://www.bing.com/search?q=");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_google);
    mSearchUrl.add("https://www.google.com/search?q=");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.s_yahoo);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.yahoo.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    mImages.add(R.drawable.amazon_white256);
    mSearchUrl.add("www.amazon.com");

    initRecyclerView();
}
private void initRecyclerView() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.lvEngines);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mImages, mSearchUrl, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: your looking for image id right ? and can you tell me what you get on viewholder.image in Log ? Try to log that and tell me what you get

Comment: @Ashish I didnt give any id to the images but they are not the same ?

Comment: so what you get on image click try to put log there and tell me what your are getting

Comment: @Ashish The first Item takes int 0, second 1 and so continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your selected item globally

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private int selectedItem = 0;
    .....
```

Then inside your `onBindViewHolder` whenever you click a new Image notify your adapter for changes in the last selected item cell.

```
   viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int previousSelectedItem = selectedItem;
                selectedItem = i;
                notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedItem);     

               viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));      
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is mSelectedItem because you didn't declared ?

Comment: And remove `selectedItem = 0;` this line from your onBindViewHolder method.

Comment: The first click works but then doesn't work the same problem.

Comment: I have taked the same condition for if and else from Housefly and it is working.

Comment: Do you know for example the bing it is the first when I click google the google will be the first will switch places with bing ?

Comment: Do you just want swap position or want to keep the sequence?

Comment: I wan't to swap position and make a little animation or do not swap but only the list animation and change position of recyclerview list

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922313/3022836) to swap item position then notify your adapter.

Comment: there is orderItems what should I write ?
It is swaping but it is mixing the images and making duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from `onBindViewHolder`

```
selectedItem = 0;
```

and add an else to the background condition, like:

```
if (selectedItem == i) {
    viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
}else{
    viewHolder.image.setBackgroundColor(“YOUR_DEFAULT_COLOR”);
}
```

and update the onClick:

```
viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedItem = i;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
});
```

Comment: @Spritzig What exactly did't work? I forgot to add the else part, you can try now.

Comment: I have writed some from your code and some from @Kunu code and it is working this.